# How do we make users to post replies as answers and not comments?

Tags: discussion, support

I've recently found that many questions on the site have excellent answers on the comments, but none on the answers page. On certain occasions, as [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/queens-gambit-declined-why-1-d4-d5-2-c4-e6-rather-than-2-bf5/6374#6374), some of the users requested that the comments were added as an answer, and so I did. However, I don't feel it right to do so in other questions as [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5401/about-possible-chess-variations), where the answer is perfect but misplaced on the comments. It would seem that I was appropriating the good answer.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Quoting comments in your answer will not help. They can be seen clearly the way they stand at the moment. Better would be to write an answer with new facts that answer the question. Some questions are answerable with a simple comment like that you linked to. I see no problem leaving it "without answer", but that is just me...

Comment: Yes, a simple comment answers the question, but aren't comments supposed to be for asking clarifications or adding relevant information, not answering the question?

Comment: True... Still, I was to lazy to write an answer, and one comment was enough to point the OP in the right direction for his research. The proper answer would be too long to write down, and I don't have time to do so because of work and other responsibilities...

Comment: Comments should clarify the question. Answers should be posted as answers, no matter how short or incomplete they are. Others can suggest improvements on the answer or post a better one later.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, but many times a comment simply answers the question. I don't want to simply copy that comment and post it as an answer (taking all the credit), I wish that user would post it himself as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to post a new comment saying

> Hey, that sounds nice! Post it as an answer instead!

It works nicely most of the time.

Comment: I've done so, and I will continue to do so. Thanks!